# How to get wishlist customer mail address in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, wishlist

How to get customer mail address who have added the product to their wish list in Magento. I don't want session customer mail id.? please help me.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following will load the wishlist of id 1 and join it to the customer table so that you will also get the email address in the collection results.

```
/** @var Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist $wishlist */
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
/** @var Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Wishlist_Collection $wishlistCollection */
$wishlistCollection = $wishlist->getCollection();
$wishlistCollection->addFieldToFilter($wishlist->getIdFieldName(), 1);
$wishlistCollection->join(
    array('customer' => $wishlistCollection->getConnection()->getTableName('customer/entity')),
    'main_table.customer_id = customer.entity_id'
);
```

Comment: Yes. This is the simplest way to get the details with the collection. I Upvote for this answer

Answer (score -1):

You can join customer attribute with email and wishlist table by customer_id

Comment: Have you got some sample code as to how this can be done?